# Regex to match 4 groups of letters/numbers, separated by hyphens

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need a regular expression that will match this pattern (case doesn't matter):

> 066B-E77B-CE41-4279

4 groups of letters or numbers 4 characters long per group, hyphens in between each group.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you put that exact string into a regular expression engine, it will match. That's not much help, but then it's not easy to know exactly what you want with such a small example. Are the digits always going to be digits? Likewise the letters? Do they have to be in a certain range? Or are they all hex digits? We need to have some idea of the pattern in order to give you a pattern match.

Comment: Should the string `ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ` give a positive match?

Comment: Yup. As long as each group is 4 characters long, contains numbers or letters, and has a hyphen between the groups, it's good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With such a small sample of data, it's not easy to be certain what you actually want.

I'm going to assume that all the characters in that string are hex digits, and that's what you need to search for.

In that case, you would need a regular expression something like this:

```
^[a-f0-9]-[a-f0-9]-[a-f0-9]-[a-f0-9]$
```

If they can be *any* letter, then replace the `f`s with `z`s.

Oh, and use `myRE.IgnoreCase = True` to make it case insensitive.

If you need further advice on regular expressions, I'd recommend http://www.regular-expressions.info/ as good site. They even have a [VB.net-specific page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vb.html).

Comment: @JJD - I'd already included info to make it work for any letter. I've edited my answer anyway to make it more useful for you, but I've left the original bit about hex in there (if nothing else, it may be useful for someone else who reads this in the future)

Answer (score 9):

```
^(?:\w{4}-){3}\w{4}$
```

Explanation:

```
    ^                  # must match beginning of string
     (?:               # make a non-capturing group (for duplicating entry)
       \w{4}           # a-z, A-Z, 0-9 or _ matching 4 times
       -               # hyphen
     ){3}              # this group matches 3 times
     \w{4}             # 4 more of the letters numbers or underscore
    $                  # must match end of string
```

Would be my best bet. Then you can use [Regex Match (static)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz.aspx).

P.S. More info on regex can be found [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

P.P.S. If you don't want to match underscores, the `\w` above can be replaced (both times) with `[a-zA-Z0-9]` (known as a class matching lowercase and uppercase letters and numbers). e.g.

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-){3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$
```

Comment: @JJD: Fixed my answer, too! ;-) See the bottom pattern to match your new question.

Comment: +1 for the non-capturing group, and elegant solution, as well as broken down description.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
[A-Za-z0-9]{4}\-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}\-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}\-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your example:

- There are four groups of letters, separated by dashes.
- Each group is four letters.
- The letters are hexadecimal digits.

This pattern would match that:

```
^[\dA-F]{4}-[\dA-F]{4}-[\dA-F]{4}-[\dA-F]{4}$
```

Note that `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of the string, which is important if you want to match the entire string and not check if the pattern occurs inside a string.

You could also make use of the repetitions in the pattern:

```
^(?:[\dA-F]{4}-){3}[\dA-F]{4}$
```