# Need help with RegEx match pattern

Tags: regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex to match 4 groups of letters/numbers, separated by hyphens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699294/regex-to-match-4-groups-of-letters-numbers-separated-by-hyphens)

Apologies in advance. I asked this question yesterday but not one of the answers worked reliably. I will try to more clearly explain things this time...

I need a Regular Expression that will match something that looks like this:

```
066B-E77B-CE41-4279
```

4 groups of 4 characters per group, separated by a hyphen. The characters can be a-z and 0-9 and case does not matter.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not learn regular expressions instead? Try out [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester/) for a great environment to experiment in. Good luck!

Comment: is it for credit cards use? Also it's better to update your previous question than create a new one

Comment: regexhero.net looks neat! A similar website that I've been using is http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Did you get a better answer this time? If not, you should explain what is not working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}
```

That matches also underscores, if you need to be more specific, you can use this:

```
[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}
```

Et cetera.

Comment: Why would the following pattern return TRUE for a match?: 066B-E77B-CE41-4279d (the D at the end should cause it to fail).

Comment: You need to add delimeters `^your_regex$` to match exactly the beginning and the end of the string. Use `\b` and/or `\B` for word boundaries, cf. http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Answer (score 2):

Using grouping function:

```
/([a-z0-9]{4}-){3}[a-z0-9]{4}/i
```

Answer (score 1):

Important on this is that the pattern is anchored at the start and the end of the string

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]{4}(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}){3}$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u80e)

If not anchored with `^` and `$` there can be anything before or ahead and the pattern would anyway return true.

A bit shorter

```
^(?i)[A-Z0-9]{4}(?:-[A-Z0-9]{4}){3}$
```

[Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u80h)

`(?i)` makes it ignore case, this syntax should work with most regex engines.